# How to speed up flask-socketio Emit

Tags: flask-socketio

I need to regularly send processed frames from opencv-python backed to a nodejs frontend. I am using flask-socketio for communication between nodejs and opencv-python.

I am able to get the output by emitting at the end of each iteration in a while loop. But the there is latency and i am not getting good enough fps.

How can i improve the FPS for real-time video processing?

I have tried async_mode of flask-socketio as eventlet which only emitted for every loop when i used sleep after the emit line. Having sleep leads to further reduction in FPS. On async_mode threading, the emit happens for every loop iteration without sleep. Which gives better FPS but still very less as compared to that without emit.

```py
vs = cv2.Videocapture(path)
while(vs.isOpened()):
     ret, fr = vs.read()
     //do some processing
     emit('frame', fr)
```

Without the emit line i am able to get 55-60 FPS but with emit i can barely achieve 20 FPS. What can i do to speed up the communication between python and nodejs

Update: Adding requirements.txt

```
aiodine==1.2.6
aiohttp==3.5.4
altgraph==0.16.1
asgiref==3.1.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.1.0
bocadillo==0.16.1
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cycler==0.10.0
dnspython==1.16.0
eventlet==0.25.0
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-SocketIO==4.1.0
future==0.17.1
greenlet==0.4.15
h11==0.8.1
idna==2.8
imutils==0.5.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
kiwisolver==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.0
minidump==0.0.6
monotonic==1.5
multidict==4.5.2
nest-asyncio==1.0.0
netifaces==0.10.6
numpy==1.16.4
object-detection==0.1
opencv-contrib-python==4.0.1.24
opencv-python==3.4.2.17
pandas==0.24.2
pefile==2019.4.18
pudb==2019.1
Pygments==2.4.2
pyparsing==2.4.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-engineio==3.8.1
python-multipart==0.0.5
python-socketio==4.1.0
pytz==2019.1
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
requests==2.22.0
six==1.12.0
starlette==0.12.0
tqdm==4.32.1
typesystem==0.2.2
urllib3==1.25.3
urwid==2.0.1
uvicorn==0.7.2
websockets==7.0
Werkzeug==0.15.4
whitenoise==4.1.2
yarl==1.3.0
```

Comment: I think combining opencv and video processing tasks with an asynchronous server is going to be problematic. Can you add the dependencies that you are using on the Python side to your question? In particular, it is important to know if you are using eventlet, gevent or any other async framework. Just copy the output of `pip freeze` to the question.

Comment: Hi @Miguel i have added the pip freeze output as asked by you. can you provide some help based on the update.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately combining CPU intensive tasks such as the image processing that you are doing with an asynchronous or multithreaded server is not a good idea.

You suggest that in the case of eventlet the "sleep" slows everything down. This is only partially correct. The sleep is the only way to enable concurrency in a greenlet based process. All the sleep does (assuming you call `sleep(0)`) is let other tasks get a share of the CPU. The problem is that while those other tasks runs, the task with the video loop has to wait.

The threading case is also expected to have performance issues, but for a different reason. In the case of multiple threads, the PIL (Python interpreter lock) will ensure that only one thread executes Python code at a time. So while you are doing the video processing, all the Socket.IO threads are blocked, and viceversa.

If you really want to have true multitasking, the best solution is to move the video processing work to a separate process from the Socket.IO server.

Comment: I am a bit new to this domain. it would be great if you could shed some light on how can i keep the video processing work on a separate process and send the output of each iteration to my frontend, that would be very helpful. What frameworks or coding paradigm can i use? Thanks for all the help @Miguel, you are awesome